# How to make my AWS EC2 RDP, to run even after closing the RDP from my computer?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, background-process, rdp

I have an AWS EC2 RDP running Windows 10. I have installed a keyboard mouse recorder which repeates my activity and I want to run my recorded activity endlessly. But this works fine till I am connected to Remote Desktop Session. But whenever I close Remote Desktop connection. The software process stops as well.

Comment: Are you using Amazon EC2 or Amazon Workspaces? I didn't know that EC2 supports Windows 10.

Comment: Yes. AWS EC2 supports Windows 10 instances.

Comment: If you are using RDP to connect to Windows 10, then quitting RDP should leave the remote computer working "as-is", without logging off. How are you disconnecting from the session?

Comment: I connect to RDP through remote desktop session software which is preinstalled on windows. Whenever I disconnect to remote session, my AWS EC2 instance stop processing in background. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: I added a bat script that close my RDP but keep alive windows session, and now it works.
for /f \"skip=1 tokens=3\" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
%windir%\\System32\\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)

I called this script as first thing on my py script

Answer (score 0):

Try add this bat script and call it as first thing on your script that simulate human.
I've used this on my python script and it works fine.

```
for /f \"skip=1 tokens=3\" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
%windir%\\System32\\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```

It will close your RDP connection but keep alive windows session.